# How to further abstract directives that have too much duplicated logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

I'm working on a codebase where multiple directive are using essentially duplicated logic with only an object that is passed through scope changing. For example:

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            someObject:"="
        },

link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {

scope.getSomeObject = function(){
...
    return scope.someObject.$$getSomeObject;
...
}
scope.saveSomeObject = function(){
...
    scope.someObject.$$saveSomeObject();
...
}
scope.removeSomeObject = function(){
...
    scope.someObject.$$removeSomeObject();
...
}
```

}

The logic for each function is more complicated but essentially what I've shown. Generally, the functions are almost exactly the same, though here and there, special cases pop up. To me it seems that directives were essentially created to solve the problem of having to write this code every time, and when a bug is found, it has to be fixed everywhere. The directives also duplicate most (but not all) of their logic in their respective templateUrls as well. What is the most sensible way to write this once and use over and over for the various object/cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a perfect use case for use of a 'required' directive.
Take a look at the docs for ['require'](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) attribute of the directive definition object.

For instance, you can define a directive called `someObject` and require it in your custom directive.

```
<my-directive some-object="somethingOnParentScope"></my-directive>
```

Inside of your `myDirective` definition you would do something like

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'someObject',


link: function( scope, element, attrs, someObjectCtrl ) {
  // if you need to make someObjectCtrl functionality available through templates, 
  // you will still need to add it to the scope
  scope.someFunction = someObjectCtrl.someFunction;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to pull out common code from directives to some shared place ,, I think you should start using services .. and then inject them into your directives

Comment: This turned out to be good advice. Thanks. I ended up using a factory to help me abstract the data and you put me on the correct path with services. Thanks.